# Automating cloth brush strokes in python only works for closed topologies

Tags: python, mesh

The code provided bellow takes the current selected object, and applies a cloth tool brush stroke on it based on a path specified by a list of coordinates (in this case a simple linear path). It works on meshes with sufficiently high resolutions that have a closed volume such as:

- An Icosphere with Subdivision 7
- A Torus with sufficient segments

[image: Examples where code works]

The very same code however does absolutely nothing at all on open meshes that do not have a closed volume. Such as the:

- The Grid Mesh with any number of subdivisions
- A circle with a NGON fill type

[image: Meshes that do not work at all]

My main question is, how can I modify this code so that it works with meshes that don't have a volume? I know that the cloth brush tool is capable of working on open meshes when using the GUI, but not with code!

My second (less important) question: Is there a way to make the results independent of mesh resolution? If not, that is fine.

Note that similar code does seem to work on open meshes when I apply the blob tool instead of the cloth brush tool.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from bpy import context

# Override context while stroke is applied
# https://github.com/christian-vorhemus/procedural-3d-image-generation/blob/master/blenderBackgroundTask.py#L54
def context_override():
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        screen = window.screen
        for area in screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                for region in area.regions:
                    if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                        return {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area, 'region': region, 'scene': bpy.context.scene} 

# Create a simple linear example path to define our brush stroke with
n = 200
x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, n)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, n)
z = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, n)
points = np.stack((x, y, z), axis=1)

# Define stroke parameters
strokes = []
for i, p in enumerate(points):
    stroke = {    
        "name": "stroke",
        "mouse": (0, 0),
        "pen_flip": False,
        "is_start": True if i==0 else False,
        "location": p,
        "size": 0.5,
        "pressure": 1.0,
        "time": float(i),
        "mouse_event" : (0, 0),
        "x_tilt" : 0,
        "y_tilt" : 0}
    strokes.append(stroke)

# Change blender to sculpt mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.sculpt.use_symmetry_x = False

# Set brush settings
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].tool_settings.unified_paint_settings.use_locked_size = "SCENE"
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].tool_settings.unified_paint_settings.unprojected_radius = 1.5
bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(sculpt_tool='CLOTH', toggle=False)
bpy.data.brushes["Cloth"].strength = 2.0
bpy.data.brushes["Cloth"].curve_preset = "SMOOTH"
bpy.data.brushes["Cloth"].auto_smooth_factor = 2.0

# Apply stroke
cntxt = context_override()
with context.temp_override(
        window = cntxt["window"],
        screen = cntxt["screen"],
        area = cntxt["area"],
        region = cntxt["region"],
        scene = cntxt["scene"]):
    bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke(stroke=strokes)

# Bring editor back to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```